# About Apex Test classes

Tags: apex, unit-test

Few questions  creating some confusion for me:

1. Do we'v to write ALL SOQL and DMLS before test.start or after test.start method ? For e.g in case of DMLs, If I'm creating test Data for an object and populating a list(say list of Accounts). Should insert DML operation of list , occur before test.start or after test.start?
2. Suppose my test class has 20 test methods. each having 5-6 queries outside test.start and test.stop . Would it give 100 SOQL error on running test class ?
3. Suppose I've 20 test classes each having 1 testmethod. Each test method has 5-6 queries outside test.start and test.stop. while deploying code when all test classes will run, would I get 100 SOQL issue ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

1) Best practice is to set up and load all your data for your test method outside the start/stop methods. In between really you should be testing your code, not creating data.

2) Each time `Test.startTest()` is called, the governor limits are reset. So the answer is you won't hit the 100 SOQL queries limit

3) Same as above

Comment: Thanks for Comments. It helps.  For point 1 , if I will write DML outside start/stop method. Isn't there is a possiblity if I've 100s of test classes, that will hit related governer limits( say 150 DML statement issue). Similary, Also For Point 2 and 3, what happens if suppose ,  Test.start and test.stop are not present in any TestMethods. I'm guessing, I'll hit governer limit(100 SOQL error) in both cases.  Just like to confirm

Comment: Each test method runs separately with a fresh set of governor limits. Here is why you should be using `startTest()` and `stopTest()` - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_tools_start_stop_test.htm